# Umbraco V7 Connection String to Access

Tags: c#, sql, web-config, connection-string, umbraco

I have created a data type of nuPickers SQL DropDown Picker, I have created the connection string within the web.Config as follows:

```
<add name ="CountriesDB" connectionString="Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\"User1"\Documents\Countries.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
```

I have connected up the Umbraco SQL dropdown picker with the following command:

Select  ID AS 'Key', CountryName AS 'Label' FROM Countries

To populate the dropdown with a list of the countries, however this isn't populating the dropdown, I have installed the various drivers however this still didn't resolve the issue.

All help is kindly appreciated.

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, you might have to get the site to allow 32 bit applications. I don't think the newer versions of IIS will run access in 64 bit mode.

In IIS, go to the application pool for your site, bring up the advanced settings, and set enable 32 bit applications to true and see if that solves your issue.